# Auto Tune Shifting

Tags: matlab, fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum, python

So i have an algorithm that gets the fundamental frequency of windows, and can shift the pitch of each window as well (by a factor of *x*). For example. if *x* is 2 and the f0 is 440, the resulting f0 would be 880.

My question is how do I actually implement this? What notes do I round to? Is rounding as simple as 
`x = desired_pitch / f0`

Comment: Look into the "Phase Vocoder" algorithm as that will shift the frequency without changing the duration in time.

Comment: I can do that, I already have that implemented. I just need to know what pitches to actually shift to to implement pitch correction

Comment: It seems as simple as you state- have you tried it and it doesn't do what you want?

Comment: Yes, the frequencies for every note (https://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreqs.html) and the audio sounds very close to the original with no "auto tune" effect

Comment: Then you aren't shifting the pitch by a factor of 2 (for example) like you think you are. Which implies the phase vocoder isn't properly implemented. Not sure what else we could say beyond that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to build the frequency tables for each note scale ex. `[B, A, G, F, E, D, C]`, you will need say what scale you will use to compare with each window pitch, of course you also have to worry that your frequency table includes major or minor chords.

But the essence of one basic autotunes works by adjusting to the `chromatic` scale, In other words, when building a chromatic frequency table you will only make very small adjustments in each piece of audio.

so just to exemplify, this is `Chromatic` frequency table, these are all the frequencies of the chromatic scale between `15.4339hz` and `987.7666hz`:

```
   15.4339
   16.3516
   17.3239
   18.3540
   19.4454
   20.6017
   21.8268
   23.1247
   24.4997
   25.9565
   27.5000
   29.1352
   30.8677
   32.7032
   34.6478
   36.7081
   38.8909
   41.2034
   43.6535
   46.2493
   48.9994
   51.9131
   55.0000
   58.2705
   61.7354
   65.4064
   69.2957
   73.4162
   77.7817
   82.4069
   87.3071
   92.4986
   97.9989
  103.8262
  110.0000
  116.5409
  123.4708
  130.8128
  138.5913
  146.8324
  155.5635
  164.8138
  174.6141
  184.9972
  195.9977
  207.6523
  220.0000
  233.0819
  246.9417
  261.6256
  277.1826
  293.6648
  311.1270
  329.6276
  349.2282
  369.9944
  391.9954
  415.3047
  440.0000
  466.1638
  493.8833
  523.2511
  554.3653
  587.3295
  622.2540
  659.2551
  698.4565
  739.9888
  783.9909
  830.6094
  880.0000
  932.3275
  987.7666
```

now imagine that your window has analyzed and returned the current frequency Ex. `237.87hz`, so based on the chromatic frequency table find what is the closest frequency to the frequency you captured, in this case it would be the frequency `233.0819` (see the table above)...

So now you can have the necessary proportion to scale your audio:

```
233.0819 / 237.87 =  0.9798709379
```

This `0.9798709379` is your Pitch shift factor that you need use to scale the actuar pitch `237.87hz` to a tuned chromatic scale `233.0819hz`

Comment: So then how would I change this based on the note for each scale?

Comment: I did a crazy algorithm that build all frequencies, starting on frequency minimum of  a midi number `minfreq=2^(-MidiNumer/12) * 440`, in one loop multiply each Freq by one semitone, `SM=2^(1/12)` (like that `minfreq = minfreq * SM`)  and then I choose only the frequencies of the major or minor chords, someone smarter than me sure did it in a simpler/better way lol...If you want a more aggressive tuning, maybe you could do the tuning on a pentatonic scale

Comment: So if the song was in A, how would I determine the frequencies to use

Comment: I can't explain my entire algorithm in a simple comment here, this is the process of the creation of all table frequencies of C, A, B, etc Major or Minor